# Convert IDN string to UTF-8

Tags: objective-c

How can I convert IDNA ASCII to UTF8 in objective-C?
For example I have the following string:

```
xn--ixaia4a8au
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't used it, but this looks like what you are looking for https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa.

Comment: I'll test and let you know! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Punycode-Cocoa

[Nate Weaver](https://derailer.org/) has published an Objective-C wrapper based on [RFC 3492](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3492)'s pure C reference implementation called [Punycode Cocoa](https://github.com/Wevah/Punycode-Cocoa):

> A simple punycode/IDNA category on NSString, based on code and documentation from RFC 3492 and RFC 3490.
>
> Use this to convert internationalized domain names (IDN) between Unicode and ASCII.
>
> To use in your own projects, all you need is `NSStringPunycodeAdditions.h/m`. This project includes a sample testing app.